# UNNotificationContentExtension not displaying

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm trying to make a custom notification alert.   I added my extension target and changed the `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` value to 'drawing'.

In my push notification I added a `"category" : "drawing"` element to the `aps` block.  The `didReceive(_:)` method from that extension is never getting called though.  What did I forget to do?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have done whats needed. I too had similar problem of not seeing the custom notification screen.
However, whats not mentioned in the documents of UNNotificationContentExtension is that the custom screen appears only when you do a 3D touch on the notification alert. I tried to do a 3D touch and the custom screen appeared. Please check.

Comment: Instead of force touch, the user can also swipe the notification to the left, and choose 'View' from the context menu.

Comment: Also, I found it works correctly if you launch the app tapping the icon on Springboard, but not launching app via Xcode in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

First check that the extension category is set appropriately in the extension info.plist file to match what is being sent in the aps block of your push notification

Second check that the deployment target for the extension is <= to the iOS version of the device you're trying to run on.

Answer (score 1):

Have u added this in your target's info.plist file instead of `ACTIONABLE` add `drawing`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, it was just that in the plist I made my `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` to be an `Array` and I wasn't adding them correctly.

**Incorrect:**

[image]

It shouldn't come next to `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` ie it shouldn't be a field of `NSExtensionAttributes`

**Correct:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

It should be a field of `UNNotificationExtensionCategory`

Apparently to learn how to use the plist you need at least 25 years of experience :)

Answer (score 0):

This method is only called once you force touch into the notification.

If you are monitoring this through LLDB, it runs as a separate process.  Make sure you're building your extension target in order to access these methods and the logs from LLDB.

Lastly, if you are like me, and you have discarded the storyboard, then you need to specify the principal class in your extensions Info.plist.  This class must be your main view controller including the target namespace.  For example, if your extension is `MyNotificationExtension` then you would set NSExtension > NSPrincipalClass to `MyNotificationExtension.MyNotificationExtensionViewController`.